# How do you append data to an existing Excel file?

Tags: c#, epplus

How do I append data to an already existing Excel file.

Let's say there can be a variable amount of rows already written to a file and I need to get the next row to write on.

I was thinking check for 2 blank rows and then write on the 2nd row or something like that.

How would I do this? Is there a way in EPPlus to open an Excel file and find the last line or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Worksheet.Dimension` should get you what you need.  So if you have a sheet like this:

[image]

You can does this:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
{
    var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
    var lastRow = ws.Dimension.End.Row;
    var lastColumn = ws.Dimension.End.Column;

    Console.WriteLine($"Last Row: {lastRow}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Last Column: {lastColumn}");
}
```

Which gives in console:

```
Last Row: 9
Last Column: 6
```